# 18.04 server Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, network-manager, systemd-networkd

My Server was working great until TimeTrex (A PHP based Payroll Application needed updating for the new Tax Tables. The install went in clean but now the system says the network is unreachable. I ran the following checks:
Running as root
Output of cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp5s0:
            addresses: [192.168.1.200/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            dhcp4: false
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Output of ip addr ls:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:de:80:28:a2:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.200/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::96de:80ff:fe28:a271/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of netplan --debug generate:

```
** (generate:2250): DEBUG: 18:39:27.761: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:2250): DEBUG: 18:39:27.762: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2250): DEBUG: 18:39:27.762: enp5s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2250): DEBUG: 18:39:27.762: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2250): DEBUG: 18:39:27.762: Generating output files..
** (generate:2250): DEBUG: 18:39:27.762: NetworkManager: definition enp5s0 is not for us (backend 1)
```

Output of systemctl status systemd-networkd:

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-01-12 18:22:40 EST; 22min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 923 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─923 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Jan 12 18:22:40 timberoakspetspa systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Jan 12 18:22:40 timberoakspetspa systemd-networkd[923]: Enumeration completed
Jan 12 18:22:40 timberoakspetspa systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Jan 12 18:22:40 timberoakspetspa systemd-networkd[923]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Jan 12 18:22:45 timberoakspetspa systemd-networkd[923]: enp5s0: Gained carrier
Jan 12 18:22:45 timberoakspetspa systemd-networkd[923]: enp5s0: Could not set route: Network is unreachable
Jan 12 18:22:47 timberoakspetspa systemd-networkd[923]: enp5s0: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 12 18:22:47 timberoakspetspa systemd-networkd[923]: enp5s0: Configured
```

Comment: i see that the gateway `192.168.0.1` is not in `192.168.1.200/24`

Answer (score 0):

help from another group showed the default gateway had been erroneously changed in the /etc/netplan/*.yaml.

Issue resolved - I think.